# working with traveling animations

Tags: javascript, animation, dhtml

I am working with taveling fish. The fish should swim across the screen from both direction. I am having a little bit hard of understanding how to set up the array so the fish could swim. The array i was thinking was like this

```
Var fishPos = new Array
fishPos[0] = fish1
fishPos[1] = fish2
fishPos[2] = fish3
```

then do the function of the fish..I really don't know how to do animated fish swim...i am trying. I guess i am woundering If the array i am looking for is what i just did up there.. Thanks.

Ok this is what I have so far but something is still not right they fish will not swim...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Fish tank</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // <![CDATA[
var fishPos = new Array(3);
var fishPos = 0; 
var direction; 
var begin; 
fishPos[0] = "fish1.gif"; 
fishPos[1] = "fish2.gif"; 
fishPos[2] = "fish3.gif";
  function fishSwim(fishNumber) {
  document.getElementById("fish"+fishNumber).style.left =  horizontal[fishPos[fishNumber]  + "px";
   ++fishPos[fishNumber];
   if (fishPos[fishNumber] == 49)
    fishPos[fishNumber] = 0;
    }
   function startSwimming() {
    setInterval(fish1Swim, 100);
   }
   // ]]>
   </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startSwimming();">
   <p><span id="fish1" style=
  "position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px"><img src="fish1.gif" alt="Image of a fish"   /></span></p>
 <p><span id="fish2" style=
 "position:absolute; left:10px; top:120px"><img src="fish3.gif" alt="Image of a fish"  /></span></p>
   <p><span id="fish3" style=
   "position:absolute; left:10px; top:250px"><img src="fish2.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching it from the wrong direction. To make it easier for you you should try using animation plugin like http://www.spritely.net/ (require jQuery).

If you wanted to make it by yourself you'd have to write a tweening function which would - over specified time - move your object from point A to B, change its animations frames, offset its Y position to give this fishy/wobbly movement effect etc. Creating array of positions isn't really the way to go.

You will find a lot of tips on how to start working on creating your own animations engine at this fine article at Dev.Opera http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-animation/

If you are targeting only the modern browsers you could try playing with CSS3 animations - though these aren't widely supported yet.

Comment: ok the book i have that i am learning from is javascript and the chapter is dynmaic HTML(DHTML) and in my book it dont explain how to do this. I am so lost and confused about this that i am trying everything i know how to use and the fishes still aint swimming.

Comment: Ouch, you've messed it up a bit :)
 1. you don't have fish1Swim function so the interval tries to call undefined function on every tick
 2. as fishPos[fishNumber] stores the filename calling pre-increment on is wrong as you can use increment/decrement operators only on variables of type Number. 
 3. then you compare stored fish name with 49 to reset its name to 0
; You've made some errors on more fundamental level then just the algorithm for creating animations so I'd review the basics of JS, read a bit on the Dev.Opera link I gave you and you should be able to pull it off on your own.

Comment: What book is it? Maybe you should try different one hehe :)

Comment: its a book i got from school...and i dont know i can call for one fish to swim that is it.

Comment: Don't want to discourage you but you should have a bit more reading on javascript - I've noticed now even more errors. Like at the very beginning you assign an array to the fishPos variable and the immediately you overwrite its value with 0 - so no more array for you. Then you try to set values for fishPos array elements - though as this isn't array anymore but a Number (0) you can't do that. Or further in the code you try to assign value from array named horizontal - which isn't declared anywhere in your code. You could try reading here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide